# Polars truncate to day of a non-utc time-zone aware datetime series

Tags: python-polars

Let's say I have:

```
test=pl.DataFrame({'dt':pl.date_range(low=datetime(2022,11,1), high=datetime(2022,11,4), interval='1h')})
```

I can do:

```
test.with_column(pl.col('dt').dt.truncate('1d').alias('trunced'))
```

and the `trunced` column comes out as expected.

```
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ dt                  ┆ trunced             │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2022-11-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2022-11-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 01:00:00 ┆ 2022-11-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 02:00:00 ┆ 2022-11-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 03:00:00 ┆ 2022-11-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 21:00:00 ┆ 2022-11-03 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 22:00:00 ┆ 2022-11-03 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 23:00:00 ┆ 2022-11-03 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-04 00:00:00 ┆ 2022-11-04 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

However, if I localize my `dt` column then it doesn't work.  For instance.

```
test=test.with_column(pl.col('dt').dt.tz_localize('America/New_York'))
test.with_column(pl.col('dt').dt.truncate('1d').alias('trunced'))

┌────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ dt                             ┆ trunced                        │
│ ---                            ┆ ---                            │
│ datetime[μs, America/New_York] ┆ datetime[μs, America/New_York] │
╞════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2022-11-01 00:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-10-31 20:00:00 EDT        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 01:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-10-31 20:00:00 EDT        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 02:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-10-31 20:00:00 EDT        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 03:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-10-31 20:00:00 EDT        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                            ┆ ...                            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 21:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-03 20:00:00 EDT        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 22:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-03 20:00:00 EDT        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 23:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-03 20:00:00 EDT        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-04 00:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-03 20:00:00 EDT        │
└────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

It looks like it's converting to UTC, then truncating, then giving back the EPT timezone representation of that.

For that matter, I get similar behavior with `strftime`

```
test.with_column(pl.col('dt').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').alias('string'))
┌────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ dt                             ┆ string              │
│ ---                            ┆ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs, America/New_York] ┆ str                 │
╞════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2022-11-01 00:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-01T04:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 01:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-01T05:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 02:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-01T06:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 03:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-01T07:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                            ┆ ...                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 21:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-04T01:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 22:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-04T02:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 23:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-04T03:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-04 00:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-04T04:00:00 │
└────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

With `strftime` it looks like it's converting to UTC before giving the string representation.

The functions of `dt` that strip out the parts work, for example, I can do this:

```
test.with_column((pl.col('dt').dt.year().cast(pl.Utf8) + pl.lit("-") + pl.col('dt').dt.month().cast(pl.Utf8).str.zfill(2) + pl.lit("-") + pl.col('dt').dt.day().cast(pl.Utf8).str.zfill(2)).str.strptime(pl.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d").alias('long_way'))

┌────────────────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ dt                             ┆ long_way   │
│ ---                            ┆ ---        │
│ datetime[μs, America/New_York] ┆ date       │
╞════════════════════════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2022-11-01 00:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 01:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 02:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-01 03:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                            ┆ ...        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 21:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-03 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 22:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-03 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-03 23:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-03 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-11-04 00:00:00 EDT        ┆ 2022-11-04 │
└────────────────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Polars contributor here: these are bugs. If you don't mind, could you please report those at the issue tracker? https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in no later than version 0.15.1